# How to interpret high support values for terminal nodes and low for more ancient nodes?

Tags: phylogenetics

I made a phylogenetic tree for about 300 species using a region of the COX1 gene. The tree looks visually meaningful: species of the same genus are all clustered together.

Then I performed a 350-replicate bootstrapping and I analyzed the support values. Surprisingly I found very low values for nodes that are more close to the root and high support values for nodes that are more close to the leaves.

Almost all nodes that split into 2 leaves have Bootstrap >95% but the ones close to the root have Bootstrap<20%.

Does that mean I chose a highly variable DNA region?
How would you re-build the tree to make it more consistent on more ancient nodes? I was thinking of using a concatenation of sequences with both high and low variability regions, but i am not sure it would work.